# Ecto: Can I update Ecto from 2.1.6 to 2.2.2 now and how to do it?

Tags: elixir, ecto

Currently I have Ecto 2.1.6 installed with Phoenix 1.3 framework. But I found that Ecto has a release 2.2.2, which supports :ignore action type for changesets, which allowes them to be discarded if, for example, there were no changes. This feature is needed for my project, but unluckily I can't update Ecto. I tried to mix deps.update ecto, mix deps.unlock ecto, mix deps.update ecto --all and so on..

So how to do it? And also may be this is not secure? Though on the 2.2 release page I see that it's dedicated to bugs fixes, so there shouldn't be breaking changes, but who knows..

**Edit:**
My deps from mix.exs file:

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.3.0", override: true},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.10"},
      {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
      {:trans, "~> 2.0"},
      {:scrivener_ecto, "~> 1.0"},
      {:scrivener_html, "~> 1.7"},
      {:arc_ecto, "~> 0.7.0"},
      {:gen_smtp, "~> 0.11"},
      {:phoenix_swoosh, "~> 0.2"},     
      {:bodyguard, "~> 2.1"},     
      {:slugger, "~> 0.2"},     
      {:coherence, "~> 0.5"}      
    ]
  end
```

Comment: `mix deps.update ecto` upgraded ecto from `2.1` to `2.2.2` in a Phoenix 1.2 project for me. Can you post the list of dependencies from your `mix.exs` file?

Comment: @Dogbert : I edited topic, please look at my deps list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to update dependencies to their latest semver compatible version is `mix deps.update`. The reason you're not getting Ecto 2.2 when running `mix deps.update ecto` is because one of your transitive dependency, `timex_ecto`, has a dependency on ecto `~> 2.1.0` and `2.2.x` is not compatible with `~> 2.1.0`.

```
├── coherence ~> 0.5 (Hex package)
│   ├── comeonin ~> 3.0 (Hex package)
│   │   └── elixir_make ~> 0.4 (Hex package)
│   ├── ecto ~> 2.0 (Hex package)
│   ├── gettext ~> 0.13 (Hex package)
│   ├── phoenix ~> 1.3 (Hex package)
│   ├── phoenix_html ~> 2.10 (Hex package)
│   ├── phoenix_swoosh ~> 0.2 (Hex package)
│   ├── timex ~> 3.1 (Hex package)
│   │   ├── combine ~> 0.7 (Hex package)
│   │   ├── gettext ~> 0.10 (Hex package)
│   │   └── tzdata ~> 0.1.8 or ~> 0.5 (Hex package)
│   │       └── hackney ~> 1.0 (Hex package)
│   ├── timex_ecto ~> 3.1 (Hex package)
│   │   ├── ecto ~> 2.1.0 (Hex package) <-- This
│   │   └── timex ~> 3.0 (Hex package)
│   └── uuid ~> 1.0 (Hex package)
```

The proper fix would be to ask the author of timex_ecto to change the dependency to `~> 2.1`. Until then, you can override the version of Ecto in your `mix.exs`:

```
defp deps do
  [
    ...,
    {:ecto, "~> 2.2", override: true}
  ]
end
```

and then run `mix deps.get`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dogbert!